# React router in wordpress theme with REST API plugin

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, react-router

Hey guys I need some help with my React app using wordpress.
Ive created a theme in wordperss which is basically my react app. I am using wordpress to serve my app using the REST API plugin. I have been able to get my app working, and successfully fetch data from the plugin api endpoint.

I cant get routing to work with my react app though, and I think this might be down to configuring the .htaccess.

So in my site I need all `/wp-` folders to work, but all other folders that I set in my `<Route>` in my react app need to be picked up by `<BrowserRouter>`

Because Im using the RESt API plugin the wordpress permalinks must be set to Post name. And so Wordpress auto generates the following htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So the thing is, how do I modify this so I can still use wordpress admin, access the JSOn feed at `wp-json` and also enable react router?

I am going round in circles trying to get this to work, if anyone can help me out that would be amazing!

Comment: _“and I think this might be down to configuring the .htaccess.”_ - well then you should probably show us what you did in that regard. _“This is the built code which my theme is using”_ - that one seems rather irrelevant to begin with.

Comment: I have updated my post to be more specific, and show the generated htaccess file

Comment: I’d try to exclude all `/wp-` paths from rewriting with `RewriteRule ^wp- - [L]`, same principle by which it is already ignoring the index.php. This should be placed at the very top, before the WP comments - so it might require `RewriteEngine On` there as well.